# Translating from SQL to R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I currently have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT sector, COUNT(sector) 
FROM clients
GROUP BY sector
ORDER BY COUNT(sector) DESC LIMIT 3;
```

So I am trying to make a move to ***tidyverse*** from SQL Developer but I am encountering difficulties when trying to run certain sequences, because obviously it's not as straightforward (or not to me at least).

So I was wondering if anyone could help me.

This is just a **basic query** from a **single table** in which I have to see **how many clients are a certain sector**.

**What is its equivalent in R?**

Can anyone assist me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, this can be achieved by getting the frequency `count` of 'sector' `arrange` the frequency column 'n' in `desc`ending order and `slice` the first 3 rows

```
library(tidyverse)
clients %>%
   count(sector) %>%
   arrange(desc(n)) %>%
   slice(1:3)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
clients <- data.frame(sector = sample(letters[1:10], 50, 
          replace = TRUE), val = rnorm(50))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sqldf` library, if you are open to it, would actually let you to continue using your SQL syntax:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT sector, COUNT(sector) 
        FROM clients
        GROUP BY sector
        ORDER BY COUNT(sector) DESC LIMIT 3"
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

The `sqldf` package runs SQLite under the hood by default, though you may change to another database flavor if you want to.  This suggestion might make sense for you if you have to port over a lot of SQL logic to R, but you don't want to take the risk of having to rewrite everything using `tidyverse`, base R, or another package.

Comment: Yes, I actually used that library in the beginning to directly translate my queries but I was a bit reprimanded for it. :P

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case.  If you need to do significant work in R, then learn R (and maybe read the @akrun answer below).  If on the other hand you just have a light need for R, but don't want to rewrite your queries, then consider my answer.